# Insert Statement Error Message

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert-update

Good Morning All

My boss helped me design a query where it populates 1.37 million lines of random data, he has now asked me to insert/update the results into a blank table. But for some reason I cannot get it to work.

The three columns are ArrivalDate, PitchType_Skey and Site_Skey. But when I run my query (See below) I get an error message and I don't know why. Can you help?

> *Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.*

Query:

```
USE Occupancy

INSERT INTO Bookings (ArrivalDate, Site_Skey, PitchType_Skey)
    SELECT        
       Time.Date, Site.Site_Skey, Site.SiteWeighting, PitchType.PitchType_Skey, 
       PitchType.PitchTypeWeighting, 
       RAND(checksum(NEWID())) * Site.SiteWeighting * PitchType.PitchTypeWeighting AS Expr1
    FROM            
       Capacity 
    INNER JOIN
       Site ON Capacity.Site_Skey = Site.Site_Skey 
    INNER JOIN
       PitchType ON Capacity.PitchType_Skey = PitchType.PitchType_Skey 
    INNER JOIN
       Time 
    INNER JOIN
       AGKey ON Time.ArrivalDayWeighting = AGKey.[Key] ON Capacity.StartDate <= Time.Date AND Capacity.EndDate >= Time.Date 
    CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT 0 AS col1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 AS col1) AS aaav
    WHERE        
       (Time.CalendarYear = 2010) 
       AND (RAND(checksum(NEWID())) * Site.SiteWeighting * PitchType.PitchTypeWeighting >= 1.22)
```

Thanks

Wayne

Comment: The error is crystal clear: your `INSERT` statement defines **3 columns** - your `SELECT` statement returns **6 columns** - this will **never** work! The number of columns **must match**

Answer (score 2):

The error message give you the answer. You have more items in your `SELECT` list (6)

```
Time.Date
Site.Site_Skey
Site.SiteWeighting
PitchType.PitchType_Skey
PitchType.PitchTypeWeighting
RAND(checksum(NEWID())) * Site.SiteWeighting * PitchType.PitchTypeWeighting AS Expr1
```

Than you do in your `INSERT` list (3)

```
ArrivalDate
Site_Skey
PitchType_Skey
```

Either remove some columns from your `SELECT` list or add some to your `INSERT` list.

As you haven't given the complete structure of your `Bookings` table I can only guess that you will need to do this

```
USE Occupancy
INSERT INTO Bookings
(
    ArrivalDate,
    Site_Skey,
    PitchType_Skey
)
SELECT
    Time.Date,
    Site.Site_Skey,
    PitchType.PitchType_Skey
FROM
    Capacity
    INNER JOIN Site ON Capacity.Site_Skey = Site.Site_Skey
    INNER JOIN PitchType ON Capacity.PitchType_Skey = PitchType.PitchType_Skey
    INNER JOIN Time
    INNER JOIN AGKey ON Time.ArrivalDayWeighting = AGKey.[Key] ON Capacity.StartDate <= Time.Date AND Capacity.EndDate >= Time.Date
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT 0 AS col1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 AS col1
    ) AS aaav
WHERE
    Time.CalendarYear = 2010
    AND (RAND(checksum(NEWID())) * Site.SiteWeighting * PitchType.PitchTypeWeighting >= 1.22)
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, So how do I only select the results I want to insert into my table?

Comment: @wafw1971: just **remove** those columns from your `SELECT` statement that you don't need / don't want .....

Comment: Hi Kevin I am very new to SQL and I am in my fourth week of learning, so that's why I keep asking questions.

Comment: Hi Marc

The query that you see helps me get the random data, if I remove them form the query will I still get the results?

Comment: I have found the solution and I cant believe how easy it was, I just un-ticked the boxes I didn't want on the Query Designer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @wafw1971 If the solution was different to that above then you should post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and I cant believe how easy it was, I just un-ticked the boxes I didn't want on the Query Designer.